# Join counts across tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have three objects `(List, ListType and GlobalList)` and am trying to get a count of the items in GlobalList with a specific global_id and a specific list_type_id.

This seems to work:

```
select count(*) from globals_lists gl, lists l where gl.global_id=946 and gl.list_id=l.id and l.list_type_id=10;
```

The structure is the following:

```
class ListType < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many: lists
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :global_lists
   belongs_to :list_type
end

class GlobalList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
end
```

Not sure how to do AR call - at this but can seem to put a where on the join. The `list_type_id` will always be `10`.

`a=GlobalList.where("global_id=?",119).joins(:list)`

How would I do this ActiveRecord call? Most of the stuff I found via Google involved named scopes, but it seems like this should be able to be done without scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach:

```
result = GlobalList
  .select("COUNT(*) AS total")
  .where("globals_lists.global_id=? AND lists.list_type_id=?",119, 10)
  .joins(:list)
```

Then you will account your result using `result.total`

Second approach is tho use `count` method instead of `select("COUNT(*) AS total")`

```
GlobalList      
  .where("globals_lists.global_id=? AND lists.list_type_id=?",119, 10)
  .joins(:list)
  .count
```

You can find more about ActiveRecord Query Interface [in Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), or directly at what you are interested in
[count](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#count) and [joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations)